# Issue after Quartz Web Restart- Quartz triggers all the scheduled jobs which has been pasted

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I setup JDBCJobStore for store jobs and schedule the jobs by Cron.

Sometimes, I will manually stop the Quartz Scheduler in order to bypass some scheduled job to be triggered for some specific purpose.

However, I face an issue after re-starting the Quartz Scheduler. All the jobs which was scheduled will be triggered at same time even through the next schedule time has been due. I check the database and find all the jobs has been scheduled and saved in QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS table, but not can be delete. Cron only re-schedule jobs after run.

Is there any way to make Quartz to re-schedule job by Cron when I re-start the Quartz Server and without trigger these expired schedule?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Best Regards, 
Dean Huang

The job will be reschedule by Cron if I configure as RAMJobStore and setup job by xml, but not JDBCJobStore.

Comment: Have you got any solution to this issue?

Comment: Not yet. Do you have any idea on it?